# How to set-up mock object to return one result at first call and Exception for the rest

Tags: mocking, moq

I'm using Moq library. I'm mocking up an instance that does all regular CRUD functionality. I would like to set it up in a way to allow only one Delete(x) call over some object and all consecutive calls to Delete(x) of the same object should return an Exception.

My Delete() method returns void.

**How do I do that?**

Some code

```
mock = new Mock<ITest>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Delete(1));
mock.Setup(m => m.Delete(3)).Throws<Exception>();
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the code talk :-)

```
    public interface ITest
    {
        void Delete(int x);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        HashSet<int> deleted = new HashSet<int>();

        var mock = new Mock<ITest>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.Delete(It.Is<int>(x => deleted.Contains(x))))
            .Throws(new InvalidOperationException("already deleted"));
        mock.Setup(m => m.Delete(It.Is<int>(x => !deleted.Contains(x))))
            .Callback<int>(x => deleted.Add(x));

        mock.Object.Delete(1);
        mock.Object.Delete(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you do something like (exact syntax may be off from memory):

```
mock.Expect(m => m.Delete(1)).Times.Exactly(1);
```

Comment: Expect is now obsolete and "Setup" should be used instead. But There's no Times method/property I could call... :(